# How do I prevent a gray screen pause during startup?

Tags: linux, boot, mac, debian, installation

The other day I installed Debian 10 on a Mac computer (Macmini3,1 Late 2009). I let the installation use the entire disk with the default partitioning and formatting options. When I boot the computer there is a 20-second gray screen delay before the Grub menu is displayed. I didn't experience this with the previous installation of Debian 9 on the same computer. With Debian 9 a gray screen was only present for a few seconds. Any clues?

Comment: Depending on models, the Mac bootloader that is directly built into the EFI firmware on the Mac could possibly be attempting to start up. After this fails, it may go to the rest of the EFI boot order, which is why GRUB starts up so late.

Comment: @Varun Narravula As far as I understand this means that the firmware uses BIOS emulation mode instead of UEFI mode. Can the problem be solved by installing a boot manager like rEFInd?

Comment: Most likely your firmware is UEFI: you can check this by testing for the presence of this directory: /sys/firmware/efi; most likely your Debian is booting UEFI because it is on a Mac, and Debian is quite happy with UEFI. Installing rEFInd would be nice, but it may or may not fix your problem depending on your model. Try it and see what happens

Comment: @VarunNarravula I have no directory named `efi` in `/sys/firmware`.

Comment: Oh, this is only in Debian. I'll edit my comment to reflect